# Plot the \coordindex in alphabetic order

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

I need to replace the index numbers in the plot by alphabetic sequence. For example, on the following graph instead of 0,1,2,..., I want to see a,b,c,...

```
\documentclass{standalone}
% This file is an extract of the PGFPLOTS manual, copyright by Christian Feuersaenger.
%   http://pgfplots.sourceforge.net/pgfplots.pdf
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\pagestyle{empty}
\usepgfplotslibrary{patchplots}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[view/h=120,xlabel=$x$,ylabel=$y$]

% replicate the vertex list to show \coordindex:

\addplot[only marks,nodes near coords={\coordindex}]
coordinates {(1,1) (2,2) (3,1)};

\addplot [red,mark=square] coordinates {(1,1) (2,2) (3,1)};

\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

My idea is to replace `\coordindex` with sum of the `\coordindex` and ascii code of "a" 97. But I don't know how to implement this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Perhaps there is an easier way but you could use a counter:

[image]

If you desire upper case labels you can use `\Alph{}` instead of `\alph{}`.

### Code:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
% This file is an extract of the PGFPLOTS manual, copyright by Christian Feuersaenger.
%   http://pgfplots.sourceforge.net/pgfplots.pdf
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\pagestyle{empty}
\usepgfplotslibrary{patchplots}

\newcounter{LabelCounter}
\newcommand{\Letter}[1]{\setcounter{LabelCounter}{\numexpr#1+1\relax}\alph{LabelCounter}}%
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[view/h=120,xlabel=$x$,ylabel=$y$]

% replicate the vertex list to show \coordindex:

\addplot[only marks,nodes near coords={\Letter{\coordindex}}]
coordinates {(1,1) (2,2) (3,1)};

\addplot [red,mark=square] coordinates {(1,1) (2,2) (3,1)};

\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```