# How to draw multiple bar charts each one with multiple different series

Tags: tikz-pgf, bar-chart

I want to draw a chart which includes multiples bar chart, and each one include  different series. This is what I ´ve already have. In this case Alg 1, Alg3,..., Alg 7 would be my multiple bar charts, and parameter1,2,3 would be my multiple series. But in this case all series have the same name, and I want different names series for each bar chart.

```
 \documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
 \usepackage{pgfplots}

 \begin{document}
 \makeatletter
 \pgfplotsset{
      calculate offset/.code={
        \pgfkeys{/pgf/fpu=true,/pgf/fpu/output format=fixed}
        \pgfmathsetmacro\testmacro{(\pgfplotspointmeta           *10^\pgfplots@data@scale@trafo@EXPONENT@y)*\pgfplots@y@veclength)}
        \pgfkeys{/pgf/fpu=false}
         },
    every node near coord/.style={
        /pgfplots/calculate offset,
         yshift=-\testmacro
       },
    }
   \pgfplotstableread{
    0 1 2    4
    1 7 3    10
    2 5 2    13  
    3 11 7    2   
    4 12 8   16   
    5 7 1   2   
    }\dataset
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[ybar,
           width=17cm,
           height=10cm,
           ymin=0,
           ymax=20,        
           ylabel={Iterations},
           xtick=data,
           xticklabels = {
           Alg1,
           Alg3,
           Alg4,
           Alg5,
           Alg6,
           Alg7
           },
          xticklabel style={yshift=-13ex},
          major x tick style = {opacity=0},
          minor x tick num = 1,
          minor tick length=0ex,
          every node near coord/.append style={
                   anchor=east,
                   rotate=90
          }
          ]
  \addplot[draw=black,fill=black!20, nodes near coords=parameter1] table[x       index=0,y index=1] \dataset; 
   \addplot[draw=black,fill=black!40, nodes near coords=parameter2] table[x    index=0,y index=2] \dataset; 
   \addplot[draw=black,fill=black!60, nodes near coords=parameter3] table[x    index=0,y index=3] \dataset; 
   \end{axis}
 \end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

What I have:

[image]
What I want:

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here a solution I have defined a counter `\mycount` which is limited to six steps and produce `A,B,....,F`, you can also use this method [Plot the \coordindex in alphabetic order](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/107640/plot-the-coordindex-in-alphabetic-order) to create your counter.

The counter is used inside `nodes near coords` to obtain the desired numbering, the `name node` keys holds the name of `node near coords` as fellows `#1-\coordindex`.

**Your code**

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
 \usepackage{pgfplots}

 \newcounter{i}
 \setcounter{i}{1}
 \def\mycount{\Alph{i}\ifnum\value{i}<6
  \stepcounter{i}
  \else
  \setcounter{i}{1}
  \fi\kern-1ex}

 \begin{document}
 \makeatletter
 \pgfplotsset{
      calculate offset/.code={
        \pgfkeys{/pgf/fpu=true,/pgf/fpu/output format=fixed}
        \pgfmathsetmacro\testmacro{(\pgfplotspointmeta           *10^\pgfplots@data@scale@trafo@EXPONENT@y)*\pgfplots@y@veclength)}
        \pgfkeys{/pgf/fpu=false}
         },
    every node near coord/.style={
        /pgfplots/calculate offset,
         yshift=-\testmacro,
       },
    name node/.style={
    every node near coord/.append style={
                   name=#1-\coordindex
                   }}
}    

   \pgfplotstableread{
    0 1 2    4   
    1 7 3    10   
    2 5 2    13  
    3 11 7    2   
    4 12 8   16   
    5 7 1   2    
    }\dataset
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[ybar,
           width=17cm,
           height=10cm,
           ymin=0,
           ymax=20,        
           ylabel={Iterations},
           xtick=data,
           xticklabels = {
           Alg1,
           Alg3,
           Alg4,
           Alg5,
           Alg6,
           Alg7
           },
          xticklabel style={yshift=-13ex},
          major x tick style = {opacity=0},
          minor x tick num = 1,
          minor tick length=0ex,
          every node near coord/.append style={
                   anchor=north,font=\scriptsize
                   }
         ]
  \addplot[draw=black,fill=black!20,name node=1,  nodes near coords=\mycount 1] table[x       index=0,y index=1] \dataset; 
  \addplot[draw=black,fill=black!40,name node=2, nodes near coords=\mycount 2] table[x    index=0,y index=2] \dataset;
  \addplot[draw=black,fill=black!60,name node=3, nodes near coords=\mycount 3] table[x    index=0,y index=3] \dataset;

   \end{axis}

   \foreach \i in{1,...,3}{
   \foreach \j in{0,1,...,5}{
   \node[anchor=east,rotate=90] at (\i-\j){parameter\kern0.5ex};}}  

 \end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

**Output**

[image]